# How to use only light mode in aplication? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a program, but as I have the mobile phone in the dark theme, some textViews have a white letter and don't appear due to the color that is placed on them.

But when I switch the phone to the lightweight theme, the textView all appear.

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the dark theme in Android Studio and only use the light theme, even when the phone is set to a dark theme.

[Light Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTd6G.jpg)

[Dark Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yigqd.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a kind of short term solution if you don't want to properly implement dark theme in your app (the one that comes to the entire OS after A10)

Set your `android:textColor=@android:attr/textColorPrimary` which automatically choose the text color based on light or dark theme

Also, since you asked what to do to prevent from that default behaviour that switches your app to the dark mode when A10 and above devices turn on system wide dark mode then

You can make your `Activity` theme a descendant of `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` or similar `AppCompat` variant . Currently all apps use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` which gives the default behaviour as above

If you decide to implement a system wide dark mode for your app, it's fairly easy, you can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme). Most of the widgets already come with dark mode support, it's just that you will have to do it for your own backgrounds etc

Comment: I use the option `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` and it works, thank you!

Comment: I'd still recommend you to add support for dark mode as it has many benefits, in production, ofcourse and because most of the devs love it including me. But in practice, it's all fair

Comment: Could you explain or indicate something to me to know how it works and improve so I don't have that problem I had.

Comment: I've linked you to an article above, it just involves extending the DayNight theme and then add a seperate `colors.xml` in `values-night` folder. Define a color in `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml`, the former takes effect in day mode and the latter in night mode. Set that color anywhere you like

Answer (score 16):

Just put this line in the launcher activity before setContentView()

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ali Nawaz. This worked seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

In your `themes.xml` your application theme's parent should be `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`, or if you wan't to use the action bar (you shouldn't), then `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`