# On some phones, the TextInputEditText component is not displayed with the correct graphical settings. Why is this happening?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputedittext

I am working on an Android application using Android Studio and I am using TextInputEditTexts to input registration fields. This is the code (Activity.xml file)

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/partitaIvaText"
      android:layout_width="118dp"
      android:layout_height="55dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      >

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextLayoutPartitaIva"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="55dp"
          android:ems="10"
          android:hint="@string/PartitaIVARequired"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:singleLine="true"
          style="@style/MyTextInputEditTextStyle"
          />

   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

here is the style.xml file:

```
    <style name="MyTextInputEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_input</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grigio_scuro</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grigio_chiaro</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor_color</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    </style>
```

and here are the 2 drawable files

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/bianco"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/marrone_primario" android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/bianco"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/marrone_secondario" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/marrone_primario"  />
</shape>
```

in the Android Studio editor, I see this [Android Studio Editor: this is how is shown on some phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6QRl.png)

But on my phone (and many others) i see this [Screenshot from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG6CF.jpg)

On some phones, it appears correctly, and I am not sure how to fix the issue (I think it might have something to do with my phone's theme, and I would like to make sure it is always displayed correctly).

I tried moving all the graphical modifications to style.xml hoping it would make a difference, but I still can't figure out how to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to find a solution thanks to the post: [How to use only light mode in aplication? Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69115751/how-to-use-only-light-mode-in-aplication-android-studio)

The problem was due to the fact that the dark theme for our application had not been implemented correctly, so I decided to directly force the light theme using this line of code before the method setContentView in all my Activities:
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`